# Pagination in label page not working (Blogger)

Tags: html, css, templates, pagination, blogger

In every label page the number of the pages are not showing up. Like here: http://www.infogeekcorp.com/search/label/Cinema, we have 81 posts with the label "Cinema", but only 10 are showing up.

When I add "?updated-max=2015-11-18T06%3A41%3A00-08%3A00&max-results=20#PageNo=2" at the end of " http://www.infogeekcorp.com/search/label/Cinema" than I can see the pages numbers, but when I click back at page 1, the numbers disappears again.

What I have now in my template:

```
div#tl-num-page{position:relative;float:left;margin:0;width:100%;padding:0 25px;}
span.displaypageNum,span.showpageOf,span.pagecurrent,span.showpage.firstpage{line-height:normal;font-size:15px;padding:5px 8px;display:inline-block;margin:4px;border-radius:1px;background:#ebebeb;font-weight:normal; font-family: oswald, arial; text-transform: uppercase; border:0px solid #ebebeb;-webkit-transition:all 300ms ease-in-out;-moz-transition:all 300ms ease-in-out;-ms-transition:all 300ms ease-in-out;-o-transition:all 300ms ease-in-out;transition:all 300ms ease-in-out}
span.displaypageNum:hover,span.pagecurrent:hover,span.showpage.firstpage:hover{background:#25bccb;color:#fff!important}
span.displaypageNum a,span.pagecurrent a,span.showpage.firstpage a{color:#4b5156}
span.displaypageNum a:hover, span.pagecurrent a:hover,span.showpage.firstpage a:hover,span.displaypageNum:hover a{color:#fff;}
span.showpageOf{background-color: #ebebeb; color:#4b5156;font-weight:normal}
span.showpageOf:before{content:"\f15c";font-family:FontAwesome;margin-right:5px}
span.pagecurrent{background:#25bccb;color:#fff}
span.pagecurrent:hover,span.showpageOf:hover{color:#4b5156}

<div id='tl-num-page'/>
    <div class='pagenav'>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[
function getParameterByName(name, url) {
    if (!url) url = window.location.href;
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)", "i"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
          function uplink(){
$('a').each(function() {
          var att = $(this).attr('href'),
              vv = $(this);
          if (att !== undefined) {
              if (att.indexOf('/search/label') != -1) {
                  if (att.indexOf('max-results') != -1) {
                      var maxval = getParameterByName('max-results', att),
                          remax=att.replace('max-results='+maxval,'max-results='+perPage);
                    vv.attr('href',remax);
                  } else {
                      if (att.indexOf('?') == -1) {
                          vv.attr('href', att + "?max-results=" + perPage);
                      }else{
                        vv.attr('href', att + "&max-results=" + perPage);
                      }
                  }
              }
          }
      });
          }
  $(function() {
uplink();
$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
      uplink();
});
  });

// Pagination
    var perPage=7;
    var numPages=6;
    var firstText ='Primeiro';
    var lastText ='Último';
    var prevText ='« Anterior';
    var nextText ='Próximo »';
var urlactivepage = location.href;
var home_page = "/";
if (typeof firstText == "undefined") firstText = "Primeiro";
if (typeof lastText == "undefined") lastText = "Último";
var noPage;
var currentPage;
var currentPageNo;
var postLabel;
pagecurrentg();
function looppagecurrentg(pageInfo) {
    var html = '';
    pageNumber = parseInt(numPages / 2);
    if (pageNumber == numPages - pageNumber) {
        numPages = pageNumber * 2 + 1
    }
    pageStart = currentPageNo - pageNumber;
    if (pageStart < 1) pageStart = 1;
    lastPageNo = parseInt(pageInfo / perPage) + 1;
    if (lastPageNo - 1 == pageInfo / perPage) lastPageNo = lastPageNo - 1;
    pageEnd = pageStart + numPages - 1;
    if (pageEnd > lastPageNo) pageEnd = lastPageNo;
    html += "<span class='showpageOf'>Página " + currentPageNo + ' de ' + lastPageNo + "</span>";
    var prevNumber = parseInt(currentPageNo) - 1;
    if (currentPageNo > 1) {
        if (currentPage == "page") {
            html += '<span class="showpage firstpage"><a href="' + home_page + '">' + firstText + '</a></span>'
        } else {
            html += '<span class="displaypageNum firstpage"><a href="/search/label/' + postLabel + '?&max-results=' + perPage + '">' + firstText + '</a></span>'
        }
    }
    if (currentPageNo > 2) {
        if (currentPageNo == 3) {
            if (currentPage == "page") {
                html += '<span class="showpage"><a href="' + home_page + '">' + prevText + '</a></span>'
            } else {
                html += '<span class="displaypageNum"><a href="/search/label/' + postLabel + '?&max-results=' + perPage + '">' + prevText + '</a></span>'
            }
        } else {
            if (currentPage == "page") {
                html += '<span class="displaypageNum"><a href="#" onclick="redirectpage(' + prevNumber + ');return false">' + prevText + '</a></span>'
            } else {
                html += '<span class="displaypageNum"><a href="#" onclick="redirectlabel(' + prevNumber + ');return false">' + prevText + '</a></span>'
            }
        }
    }
    if (pageStart > 1) {
        if (currentPage == "page") {
            html += '<span class="displaypageNum"><a href="' + home_page + '">1</a></span>'
        } else {
            html += '<span class="displaypageNum"><a href="/search/label/' + postLabel + '?&max-results=' + perPage + '">1</a></span>'
        }
    }
    if (pageStart > 2) {
        html += ' ... '
    }
    for (var jj = pageStart; jj <= pageEnd; jj++) {
        if (currentPageNo == jj) {
            html += '<span class="pagecurrent">' + jj + '</span>'
        } else if (jj == 1) {
            if (currentPage == "page") {
                html += '<span class="displaypageNum"><a href="' + home_page + '">1</a></span>'
            } else {
                html += '<span class="displaypageNum"><a href="/search/label/' + postLabel + '?&max-results=' + perPage + '">1</a></span>'
            }
        } else {
            if (currentPage == "page") {
                html += '<span class="displaypageNum"><a href="#" onclick="redirectpage(' + jj + ');return false">' + jj + '</a></span>'
            } else {
                html += '<span class="displaypageNum"><a href="#" onclick="redirectlabel(' + jj + ');return false">' + jj + '</a></span>'
            }
        }
    }
    if (pageEnd < lastPageNo - 1) {
        html += '...'
    }
    if (pageEnd < lastPageNo) {
        if (currentPage == "page") {
            html += '<span class="displaypageNum"><a href="#" onclick="redirectpage(' + lastPageNo + ');return false">' + lastPageNo + '</a></span>'
        } else {
            html += '<span class="displaypageNum"><a href="#" onclick="redirectlabel(' + lastPageNo + ');return false">' + lastPageNo + '</a></span>'
        }
    }
    var nextnumber = parseInt(currentPageNo) + 1;
    if (currentPageNo < (lastPageNo - 1)) {
        if (currentPage == "page") {
            html += '<span class="displaypageNum"><a href="#" onclick="redirectpage(' + nextnumber + ');return false">' + nextText + '</a></span>'
        } else {
            html += '<span class="displaypageNum"><a href="#" onclick="redirectlabel(' + nextnumber + ');return false">' + nextText + '</a></span>'
        }
    }
    if (currentPageNo < lastPageNo) {
        if (currentPage == "page") {
            html += '<span class="displaypageNum lastpage"><a href="#" onclick="redirectpage(' + lastPageNo + ');return false">' + lastText + '</a></span>'
        } else {
            html += '<span class="displaypageNum lastpage"><a href="#" onclick="redirectlabel(' + lastPageNo + ');return false">' + lastText + '</a></span>'
        }
    }
    var blogPager = document.getElementById("tl-num-page");
    if (blogPager) {
        blogPager.innerHTML = html
    }
}
function totalcountdata(root) {
    var feed = root.feed;
    var totaldata = parseInt(feed.openSearch$totalResults.$t, 10);
    looppagecurrentg(totaldata)
}
function pagecurrentg() {
    var thisUrl = urlactivepage;
    if (thisUrl.indexOf("/search/label/") != -1) {
        if (thisUrl.indexOf("?updated-max") != -1) {
            postLabel = thisUrl.substring(thisUrl.indexOf("/search/label/") + 14, thisUrl.indexOf("?updated-max"))
        } else {
            postLabel = document.body.getAttribute('data-label')
        }
    }
    if (thisUrl.indexOf("?q=") == -1 && thisUrl.indexOf(".html") == -1) {
        if (thisUrl.indexOf("/search/label/") == -1) {
            currentPage = "page";
            if (urlactivepage.indexOf("#PageNo=") != -1) {
                currentPageNo = urlactivepage.substring(urlactivepage.indexOf("#PageNo=") + 8, urlactivepage.length)
            } else {
                currentPageNo = 1
            }
            document.write("<script src=" + home_page + "feeds/posts/summary?max-results=1&alt=json-in-script&callback=totalcountdata><\/script>")
        } else {
            currentPage = "label";
            if (thisUrl.indexOf("max-results=") == -1) {
                perPage = 20
            }
            if (urlactivepage.indexOf("#PageNo=") != -1) {
                currentPageNo = urlactivepage.substring(urlactivepage.indexOf("#PageNo=") + 8, urlactivepage.length)
            } else {
                currentPageNo = 1
            }
            document.write('<script src="' + home_page + 'feeds/posts/summary/-/' + postLabel + '?alt=json-in-script&callback=totalcountdata&max-results=1"><\/script>')
        }
    }
}
function redirectpage(numberpage) {
    jsonstart = (numberpage - 1) * perPage;
    noPage = numberpage;
    var nameBody = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var newInclude = document.createElement('script');
    newInclude.type = 'text/javascript';
    newInclude.setAttribute("src", home_page + "feeds/posts/summary?start-index=" + jsonstart + "&max-results=1&alt=json-in-script&callback=finddatepost");
    nameBody.appendChild(newInclude)
}
function redirectlabel(numberpage) {
    jsonstart = (numberpage - 1) * perPage;
    noPage = numberpage;
    var nameBody = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var newInclude = document.createElement('script');
    newInclude.type = 'text/javascript';
    newInclude.setAttribute("src", home_page + "feeds/posts/summary/-/" + postLabel + "?start-index=" + jsonstart + "&max-results=1&alt=json-in-script&callback=finddatepost");
    nameBody.appendChild(newInclude)
}
function finddatepost(root) {
    post = root.feed.entry[0];
    var timestamp1 = post.published.$t.substring(0, 19) + post.published.$t.substring(23, 29);
    var timestamp = encodeURIComponent(timestamp1);
    if (currentPage == "page") {
        var pAddress = "/search?updated-max=" + timestamp + "&max-results=" + perPage + "#PageNo=" + noPage
    } else {
        var pAddress = "/search/label/" + postLabel + "?updated-max=" + timestamp + "&max-results=" + perPage + "#PageNo=" + noPage
    }
    location.href = pAddress
}   //]]>
        </script>
```

I really don't know what's going on. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Seems you suppose to make ajax call but actually don't do that.Check your console in browser and you will probably get some errors there.